# MySQL: Insert a new row at a specific primary key, or alternately, bump all subsequent rows down?

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating two tables in a database in MySQL just so I can play around with SQL and learn more, as I am a novice. I have read several questions on Stack relating to inserting a new row, and updating an existing row. My question is a little different, hopefully it won't be considered a dupe as none of the other answers I read gave me the full explanation I need because I think it's the auto-increment part that's confusing me. I don't think I can just go in and assign a new value for the primary keys in one of the tables with auto-increment set up, can I?

I have two tables: english_words and spanish_words. Their primary keys are respectively eng_id and span_id, and are set up to auto-increment. My hope had been to practice SQL and eventually get things set up enough so that I can practice my joins later on. For now, in english_words, I entered a duplicate row by mistake, with the ID 7. I deleted that row, and of course it now goes "6...8..." ..... and when I created my spanish_words table, I forgot all about the missing row 7. I'd hoped to keep everything very simple and aligned between the two tables until I'm ready for more complex endeavors later. Is there a way I can either:

- Bump row 7 (and all subsequent rows) down by one in my spanish_words (so 7 becomes 8, 8 becomes 9, etc)

OR

- Pull up everything after row 6 in english_words?

OR

- Is there a better solution than either of those that you could suggest?

It's possible there's not a way. Originally I'd thought of trying to UPDATE the row 7 data in english_words or maybe insert a new row, but in my research I found an answer on Stack that said you can't insert data into a specific row in the table...and then I realized that's not going to fix anything anyway.

Do those of you more experienced with SQL have any ideas? (Aside from not making such silly mistakes anyway).

Additionally, I'm open to scrapping my tables and starting again, if there's a best-practice that I'm missing. Would setting up a foreign key to correspond between the two tables be a way to fix this? I'm pretty sure you have to do that anyway to perform the joins, but I was going to cross that bridge when I get there. What is best practice amongst database admins - set up foreign keys early on, or later when you need them?

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: Altering the primary key of a row is usually a bad idea as that will cause references to that row to be incorrect. Why not create another column specifically to track their relative position? If this is a one-shot thing to fix a mistake, try `UPDATE x SET eng_id=eng_id+1 WHERE eng_id>7` where `x` is your table.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why does it matter if you skip an ID in the `english_words` table? If you require that `eng_id = span_id` for related words, you're designing the database wrong. You should have a separate column that links related IDs in the two tables, or use a separate relation table.

Comment: You don't want to bump all subsequent rows down. Consider a table of 100 million rows. Find another solution.

Comment: I think I can quote [The Ten Commandments of Access](http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm): *"Thou shalt not use Autonumber* (i.e. `auto_increment`) *if the field is meant to have meaning for thy users."* I know you're not using Access, but I think this rule applies to any RDBMS, including MySQL.

Comment: Those are good answers you guys, thank you. I knew I'd get some wisdom out of Stack! EJP, that's kind of my thought - it won't do me any good to learn how to do a crappy fix, I probably should have designed things better. I will try out these methods and rules that you guys have brought up, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to set this up is to create a relation table:

```
CREATE TABLE translation (
    eng_id int,
    span_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (eng_id) REFERENCES english_words (eng_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (span_id) REFERENCES spanish_words (span_id)
)
```

This is better than using a foreign key in the original tables, because you can't have bidirection foreign keys (you have to create the referenced row before the referencing row, so whichever table you insert into first can't have a foreign key pointing to the other one).

Comment: That seems like a much smarter way to set it up in the first place, and I forgot all about the table referenced in a foreign key having to already exist! I definitely would have tangled myself up worse. I'm going to give this solution a shot first thing, thank you!!!

Comment: Okay, went to apply this to what I'd already built (creating this new table in DB) and it wasn't working - I'm sure it's something I was doing wrong, and I did try including a semi-colon at the end lol :) First it said syntax error, then it was "Cannot add foreign key constraint"...so  I decided to scrap my original efforts overall as a bad job, and start again from scratch - I think you're right. It was poor design on my part, and part of learning better practices is doing it the RIGHT way. I'm going to try using a relational table like you suggested here. Any other tips for good design?

Comment: And for the sake of improvement, do you recommend auto-increment or not, for the primary key columns? My thought had been that although this particular db will be just a very small "practice" effort, I will be dealing with very large DBs in the future and if I needed to create something of my own in those terms, auto-increment might be a better option than manually entering the integer for each row's key. What are your thoughts on auto-increment?

Comment: If you need a unique ID for each row that isn't inherent in the data, auto-increment is definitely the way to go.